# emulator not showing message box

Tags: php, android, messagebox

I want to display a message box after getting a JSON response from server.in the code given below the database is updating properly but message box is not shown.It simply shows "Unfortunately,myapp has stopped" message.i dont know where actually the code went wrong.NOo error found in the coding.
here is my .java file

```
package com.example.loga;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity1 extends Activity {

     private ProgressDialog pDialog;

     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        EditText inputuserid;
        EditText inputserverid;

        private static String url_register = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/register.php";
        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";





    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
         // Edit Text
        inputuserid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        inputserverid= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread
                new add().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity1, menu);
        return true;
    }
    class add extends AsyncTask<String, String,String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity1.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("your Registration is processing..wait for few sec..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
              String userid = inputuserid.getText().toString();
              String serverid = inputserverid.getText().toString();

              // Building Parameters
              List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid",userid));
              params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serverid", serverid));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register,
                    "POST", params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try
            {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                AlertDialog alertDialog;
                alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity1.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("password verification..");
                alertDialog.setMessage("success.!!");
                alertDialog.show();

                 finish();
             } else {
                 // failed to create product
             }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

and my PHP file is:

```
<?php
$response = array();
 // check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['userid']) && isset($_POST['serverid']))
{

    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $serverid= $_POST['serverid'];
       // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO opass(User_ID, Server_ID ) VALUES('$userid', '$serverid')");


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) 
{
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = " Registered successfully";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
 else 
{
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
 else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

so of my logcat error:

```
04-21 17:00:14.941: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
. 
.
.
.
.
4-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$add.doInBackground(MainActivity1.java:97)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$add.doInBackground(MainActivity1.java:1)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
04-21 17:00:14.921: E/AndroidRuntime(27578):    ... 4 more
04-21 17:00:14.992: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:00:17.361: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578): Activity com.example.loga.MainActivity1 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d28880 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-240,77} that was originally added here
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.loga.MainActivity1 has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d28880 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-240,77} that was originally added here
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$add.onPreExecute(MainActivity1.java:81)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$1.onClick(MainActivity1.java:58)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 17:00:17.941: E/WindowManager(27578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 17:00:17.941: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 317 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:05:16.065: I/Process(27578): Sending signal. PID: 27578 SIG: 9
04-21 17:16:06.902: E/Trace(27969): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-21 17:16:08.042: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 107 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:08.122: D/gralloc_goldfish(27969): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-21 17:16:47.102: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:48.292: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:49.062: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 224 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:52.293: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:52.652: D/dalvikvm(27969): GC_CONCURRENT freed 152K, 11% free 2610K/2904K, paused 7ms+111ms, total 231ms
04-21 17:16:53.564: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:54.021: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(27969): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
04-21 17:16:54.021: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(27969):   in android.widget.EditText{40d27d40 VFED..CL .F....I. 90,74-228,104 #7f080007 app:id/editText2}
04-21 17:16:54.021: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(27969):   0: sent at 109014528000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=109014528, downTime=109014528, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
04-21 17:16:54.721: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 109 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:56.826: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 89 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:57.531: I/Choreographer(27969): Skipped 275 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:16:57.831: D/AndroidRuntime(27969): Shutting down VM
04-21 17:16:57.831: W/dalvikvm(27969): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at com.example.loga.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:51)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$add.onPostExecute(MainActivity1.java:97)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at com.example.loga.MainActivity1$add.onPostExecute(MainActivity1.java:1)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-21 17:16:57.981: E/AndroidRuntime(27969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 17:16:58.221: D/dalvikvm(27969): GC_CONCURRENT freed 214K, 12% free 2812K/3164K, paused 71ms+19ms, total 322ms
04-21 17:17:01.412: I/Process(27969): Sending signal. PID: 27969 SIG: 9
04-21 17:17:02.322: E/Trace(28003): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-21 17:17:02.862: I/Choreographer(28003): Skipped 125 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 17:17:02.892: D/gralloc_goldfish(28003): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
```

help me to find any mistakes i did.
thanks:)

Comment: Use debugging, see logcat..check error..that will help..

Comment: How can you be sure this is not failing? JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_register,   "POST", params);

Comment: logcat shows 04-21 16:57:10.492: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 16:57:13.182: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-21 16:57:13.842: I/Choreographer(27578): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: are you saying the command fails? i am new to android.help me  to fix

Comment: @logurani  mention line no 97 in your code.

Comment: no code in that line no

Comment: please mention before or after line 97. because you can edit your code.

Comment: sorry only 83 lines in my java file

Answer (score 0):

you can not run

```
  AlertDialog alertDialog;
  alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity1.this).create();
  alertDialog.setTitle("password verification..");
  alertDialog.setMessage("success.!!");
  alertDialog.show();
```

this on a `thread` different from the  `UI thread`

Use an `Handler` or `runOnUiThread()`

EDIT change the part whit the dialog in this way:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {

        AlertDialog alertDialog;
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity1.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("password verification..");
        alertDialog.setMessage("success.!!");
        alertDialog.show();
   }

});
```

Comment: i am newer to this.pls suggesst ant tutorial or link

Comment: thanks alot.i it is still loading with a command "your registration is processing..wait for few sec.." for 3 mins.anything wrong with my coding?

Comment: it means onPostExecute is never called